# Zero tensors in the tensor product of two vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

If V and W are two finite dimentional vector spaces over a field k, then we know that for $x\otimes y \in V\otimes W$ we have $x\otimes y =0$  if and only if x=0 or y=0$. But if one of the spaces is of infinite dimension,  is this property still true?

Comment: What proof do you have that does not apply just as well in the infinite-dimensional case?

Comment: @EricWofsey by using finite basis B and B' of V and W respectively, we have $B\otimes B'$ is a finite basis of $V\otimes W$.

Comment: Alright, now just do the same thing but omit the word "finite".